# Trellis Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, block

I want to create a diagram like that 
[image]

so far I am here, can someone help?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20]
\tikzstyle{observation}=[shape=rectangle,draw=orange!50,fill=orange!20]
\tikzstyle{lightedge}=[<-, dashed]
\tikzstyle{mainstate}=[state,very thick]
\tikzstyle{mainedge}=[<-,very thick]
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
% 1st column
\node               at (0,6) {$t=0$};
\node               at (-1.5,5) {$s_1=00$};
\node               at (-1.5,4) {$s_2=01$};
\node               at (-1.5,3) {$s_3=10$};
\node               at (-1.5,2) {$s_4=11$};
\node[mainstate] (s1_1) at (0,5) {$s_1$};
\node[state] (s2_1) at (0,4) {$s_2$};
\node[state] (s3_1) at (0,3) {$s_3$};
\node[state] (s4_1) at (0,2) {$s_4$};
\node at (0,1) {Node1};
% 2nd column
\node               at (2,6) {$t=1$};
\node[mainstate] (s1_2) at (2,5) {$s_1$}
    edge[mainedge] (s1_1);
\node[mainstate] (s2_2) at (2,4) {$s_2$}
     edge[lightedge] (s1_1);

\node[state] (s3_2) at (2,3) {$s_3$};

\node[state] (s4_2) at (2,2) {$s_4$};

\node at (2,1) {Node2};
% 3rd column
\node               at (4,6) {$t=2$};
\node[mainstate] (s1_3) at (4,5) {$s_1$}
    edge[mainedge]  (s1_2);

\node[mainstate] (s2_3) at (4,4) {$s_2$}
    edge[lightedge] (s1_2);

\node[mainstate] (s3_3) at (4,3) {$s_3$}
    edge[mainedge] (s2_2);    
\node[mainstate] (s4_3) at (4,2) {$s_4$}
    edge[lightedge] (s2_2);
\node at (4,1) {Node3};
% 4th column
\node               at (6,6) {$t=3$};
\node[mainstate] (s1_4) at (6,5) {$s_1$}
    edge[mainedge]  (s1_3)
    edge[mainedge]  (s3_3);
\node[mainstate] (s2_4) at (6,4) {$s_2$}
    edge[lightedge] (s1_3)
    edge[lightedge] (s3_3);
\node[mainstate] (s3_4) at (6,3) {$s_3$}
    edge[mainedge] (s2_3)
    edge[mainedge] (s4_3);
\node[mainstate] (s4_4) at (6,2) {$s_4$}
    edge[lightedge] (s2_3)
    edge[lightedge] (s4_3);
\node at (6,1) {Node4};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @Bernard It is spelled ["trellis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trellis_modulation) not "treillis"

Comment: @dexteritas: OK, but does it come from?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, there is also an image of a Trellis diagram on the linked page.

Comment: OK, I see: someone translated the French mathematical term `treillis` into the English `trellis` (which corresponds rather to `treillage` in French). Am I right?

Comment: @Bernard correct

Comment: I've put the title in its initial state. I was very surprised by this term, as usually `treillis` is `lattice` in algebra, and thought of a typo or misspelling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my approach. I made commands for the edges and the inputs and outputs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{lightedge}=[blue]
\tikzstyle{mainedge}=[red,very thick]
\tikzstyle{inputBit}=[rectangle,fill=red, text=white]
\tikzstyle{outputBit}=[rectangle,fill=blue, text=white]
\tikzstyle{pointer}=[orange,->,dashed]

\newcounter{ctra}
\newcommand{\trellisEdges}[2]{%
    \setcounter{ctra}{#2}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xplusone}{#1 + 1}
    \ifodd\value{ctra}
        \draw[mainedge] (s#1#2) -- (s\xplusone2);
    \else
        \draw[mainedge] (s#1#2) -- (s\xplusone0);
    \fi%
    \ifodd\value{ctra}
        \draw[lightedge] (s#1#2) -- (s\xplusone3);
    \else
        \draw[lightedge] (s#1#2) -- (s\xplusone1);
    \fi%
}

% #1=x; #2=y; #3=In; #4=Out
\newcommand{\trellisInOut}[4]{
    \node[inputBit] (in#1) at (#1+0.5,5) {#3};
    \node[outputBit] (out#1) at (#1+0.5,6) {#4};
    \draw[pointer] (in#1) -- (#1+0.5,#2);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=-1cm]
    \node at (-0.5,0) [left] {$s_1=00$};
    \node at (-0.5,1) [left] {$s_2=01$};
    \node at (-0.5,2) [left] {$s_3=10$};
    \node at (-0.5,3) [left] {$s_4=11$};

    % Nodes
    \foreach \x in {0,...,3} {
        \node at (\x,-.7) {$t=\x$};
        \foreach \y in {0,...,3} {
            \node (s\x\y) at (\x,\y) [circle,fill=blue] {};
        }
        \node at (\x,4) {
            \pgfmathparse{\x+1}
            Node \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0]{\pgfmathresult}
        };
    }

    % Edges
    \trellisEdges{0}{0}
    \trellisEdges{1}{0}
    \trellisEdges{1}{1}
    \trellisEdges{2}{0}
    \trellisEdges{2}{1}
    \trellisEdges{2}{2}
    \trellisEdges{2}{3}

    % Inputs and Outputs
    \node at (-0.5,5) [left] {Input Bits};
    \node at (-0.5,6) [left] {Output Bits};

    \trellisInOut{0}{0.5}{1}{11}
    \trellisInOut{1}{2.0}{1}{01}
    \trellisInOut{2}{2.5}{0}{01}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a starting point, I've done a matrix `s` with only the circle nodes, to have an easy reference `s-row-column`.

The rest of the nodes and paths are positioned referring to that matrix.

If you find a node like `$(node1-name)!.5!(node2-name)$`, it refers to a node which is half way (`.5`) between `node1` and `node2`.

Let me know if you have some difficulties in completing the picture.

BTW, use `tikzset` instead of `tikzstyle`, which is deprecated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, calc, intersections, arrows, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{% use tikzset not tikzstyle
    state/.style={shape=circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20},
    bits/.style={rectangle, text width=1.5em, align=center, text=white},
    greendashed/.style={-angle 60, dashed, green, thick},
    bluethick/.style={-angle 60,very thick, blue, line width=2pt},
    blueline/.style={blue, thick},
    redline/.style={red, thick},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[%
    matrix of math nodes,
    nodes={state},
    column sep=4em, row sep=7ex,
    ] (s) {%
        s_{1} & s_{1} & s_{1} & s_{1} \\
        s_{2} & s_{2} & s_{2} & s_{2} \\
        s_{3} & s_{3} & s_{3} & s_{3} \\
        s_{4} & s_{4} & s_{4} & s_{4} \\
    };
    \foreach \num/\bb in {1/00, 2/01, 3/10, 4/11}{%
        \node[left = of s-\num-1, red] {$s_{\num}=\bb$};
    }
    \foreach \numcol in {1, 2, ..., 4}{%
        \node[above =3ex of s-1-\numcol] {$t_{\numcol}$};
        \node[below =3ex of s-4-\numcol] {Node $\numcol$};
    }
    \node[bits, fill=red, below =12ex of $(s-4-1)!.5!(s-4-2)$] (Ain) {$\mathbf{1}$};
    \node[bits, fill=red, below =12ex of $(s-4-2)!.5!(s-4-3)$] (Bin) {$\mathbf{1}$};
    \node[bits, fill=red, below =12ex of $(s-4-3)!.5!(s-4-4)$] (Cin) {$\mathbf{0}$};
    \node[left=3em of Ain] {Input bits};
    \node[bits, fill=blue, below =3ex of Ain] (Aout) {$\mathbf{11}$};
    \node[bits, fill=blue, below =3ex of Bin] (Bout) {$\mathbf{01}$};
    \node[bits, fill=blue, below =3ex of Cin] (Cout) {$\mathbf{01}$};
    \node[left=3em of Aout] {Output bits};
    \foreach \icol [evaluate=\icol as \isucc using int(\icol+1)] in {1,2,3}{%
        \draw[redline] (s-1-\icol) -- node[above, black, font=\scriptsize] {$00$} (s-1-\isucc);
    }
    \draw[bluethick] (s-1-1) -- node[draw=blue, thin, fill=blue!20, rectangle, rounded corners, above=5pt, text=black, font=\scriptsize] {$11$} (s-2-2);
    \foreach \icol [evaluate=\icol as \isucc using int(\icol+1)] in {2,3}{%
        \draw[blueline] (s-1-\icol) -- node[above=2pt, black, font=\scriptsize] {$11$} (s-2-\isucc);
    }
    \draw[greendashed] (Ain) -- ($(s-2-1.north east)+(0.5,-0.5)$) to[out=90, in=240] ($(s-1-1)!.25!(s-2-2)-(1pt,1pt)$);
    \draw[greendashed] ($(s-1-1)!.60!(s-2-2)-(1pt,1pt)$) to[out=-90, in=90] ($(Ain.north east)+(0,.7)$) to[out=-90, in=0] (Aout.east);
    \matrix[above=7ex of s, column sep=.7em]{%
        \draw[redline] (0,.25) -- (1,.25); & \node[font=\scriptsize] {Path when the input is 0}; \\
        \draw[blueline] (0,.25) -- (1,.25); & \node[font=\scriptsize] {Path when the input is 1}; \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would set output bits in blue rectangles in white color, now are almost invisible.  I draw many trellis diagrams, but no one so fancy :)

Comment: @Zarko Corrected, with some refinements :)